# I see a lot of windows exe running on GPU how to remove them?

Tags: gpu

I am getting a lot of out of memory error in NVIDIA GPU. On running nvidia-smi I see a lot of Windows .exe processes using GPU.

I am not sure if they are using memory or not as it is showing as N/A. How to stop these processes from using GPU and switch them to use CPU .

programs like

```
YourPhone.exe
artMenuExperienceHost.exe
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 461.72       Driver Version: 461.72       CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 207... WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   48C    P5    16W /  N/A |   7422MiB /  8192MiB |     89%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A       548    C+G   ...ekyb3d8bbwe\YourPhone.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1688    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2924    C+G   ...artMenuExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5588    C+G   ...nputApp\TextInputHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5960    C+G   ...icePlugin\SelfService.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8436    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\SearchApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13436    C+G   ...trationBackGroundTask.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     15808      C   ...da\envs\tf_env\python.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17116    C+G   ...Browser\CtxWebBrowser.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17612    C+G   ...kyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     21476    C+G   ...rvice\ePowerButton_NB.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have another GPU for those processes to run on?

Comment: @Mokubai - I am not sure if Intel GPU is also considered for this . I have added the screenshot in question .

Comment: Is it a laptop? A desktop might "prefer" the high power GPU, but I'm pretty sure you can choose in the Nvidia settings on a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

These processes are running (they are al standard Windows processes that run in the background most of the time) but they are NOT running directly on the GPU.

These are **not** CUDA or OpenGL capable programs, so they are not able to run anything directly on the GPU.

That is why is says "N/A". That means "Not Applicable".

Answer (score 0):

These programs are not running on your GPU.  This list shows the applications that are consuming GPU resources.  These are applications that are running and are/can display on your screen, hence them being listed.  Just displaying 2D graphics is insignificant and uses little resourced.  If you were to run game, then you would see the resource usage grow for that games executable.